# Convert $.post to $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post

I want to convert my `$.post` call to `$.ajax` call because I need to clean the cache for every call.

My `$.post` call is as follows:

```
        $.post("test",   
            function(data) {
                $("#test").html(data);
                initTest();
            }
        ).success(function(){
            $('.box1').hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
            $('.box3').show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
        });
```

I tried this but it doesn't work...

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "test",
          success: function (data) {
              $("#test").html(data);
              $('.box1').hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
              $('.box3').show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
          },
          dataType: "json",
          cache: false
    });
```

Comment: Did you bother to read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)? It's the very first thing it mentions.

Comment: yep.. of course.. but it doesn't work

Comment: What doesnt work? Maybe because of url = "test" ?

Comment: url = "test" works using $post but doesn't work using ajax

Comment: No erros, nothing is happen? Even on .fail() handler?

Comment: what's the error? if you don't know look in your console or catch the error with an error function like this `error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert(thrownError); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   method:"POST",
   url : "test.php",
   success : function(data) {
                $("#test").html(data);
                initTest();
                 $('.box1').hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
     $('.box3').show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
            },
   cache : false
});
```

UPDATE
I think you have problem in parsing data. In `$.post` by default is `html dataType`. In `$.ajax` call you changed it on "json". If no json is responsed so you have parse error and success handler dont call.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax('test')
    .done(function() {
      $('.box1').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
      $('.box3').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    })
    .fail(function() { alert('error'); })
    .always(function() { alert('complete'); });
```